# How to use only a portion of GoogleMaps map?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to use only a small portion of Google Maps, like only an area of 4 km².

I have tried looking for any post with same interests, i tried in google, and SO, but found nothing related to what i have in mind. maybe i didn't know what to look for exactly.

Also, will i be able to make the map and all, while being out of the map zone ?
( i dunno how to explain this, but say, you're in city A, and the zone you want to add in your app, is in city B, would it be possible ? ).

Comment: Are you looking for Lite Mode map?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite

Comment: No, say you have a big city, i want to only take a 4 km² area, and use it in app. just that portion is to be used, nothing more.

Comment: Look at a map address in a browser: `https://www.google.com/maps/@[RandomCoordinates],11z`. Note that `11z`. Change it to `10z` or use another different number. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also, to answer to a user directly, type `@` followed by the first letters of the user you want to reply to, then select the appropriate one by clicking. Such the user gets notified. Otherwise, he might never see your answer.

Comment: @Herb, thank you for the tip, as for the reply, i'm afraid it doesn't answer what i have in mind.

How can we limit the map in an app, to never exit Central Park, New York.
You'll use the portion of Central Park, and in the app, the user won't be able to exit Central Park's borders.

How to achieve this ? if achievable at all.

Answer (score 0):

The zoom level 1 will map earth equator to 256 pixels. Now every subsequent zoom level magnifies by a level of 2 so half the meters per pixel for every zoom level. So you have to add a function that calculate zoom level such that it will display `4km` area.

Add below function in your code to display map area `~4km`.

```
private int getZoomLevel(int screenWidth) {
    double equatorLength = 40075004;  //Length is in meters
    double width = screenWidth;
    double meters = equatorLength / 256;
    int zoomLevel = 1;
    while ((meters * width) > 4000) {
        meters /= 2;
        ++zoomLevel;
    }

    return zoomLevel;
}
```

Comment: won't this one show 4km of any place ? 

how can we show, say only Central Park, a map of Central Park only, when you get to its borders, you wont see anything else, just what's inside of those 4 km.

Comment: To show for particular place you need to add latitude and longitude of that location. Why don't you use map preview if you want to just display static map area?

Comment: the map wont be static inside, it'll have locations of places, and many things, and needs to show which way to take and things like that.